# How to obtain emmeans of a trait depending on multiple variables in an unbalanced dataset?

Tags: emmeans

I collected data in experiments (n = 3) where I grew plants in two different night temperatures (20°C or 30°C). In this unbalanced dataset (different number of plant repetitions per experiment and night temperature) I fitted the following linear mixed model:

```
fit_rosette <- lmer(leaf area ~ genotype + night temperature + experiment + plant repetition + (1|experiment_setup), data = rosette)
```

The class of the variables included in the model are as following: genotype (factor), night temperature (factor), experiment (numeric), repetition (numeric) and experimental setup (numeric).

In the next step, I would like to obtain the emmeans for each genotype in the respective night temperature where the plants grew, but also separately for the experiment and plant repetition. For this, the following command was used, with cov.reduce = FALSE so the numeric variables would be treated as factor:

```
fit_rosette_emm <- emmeans(fit_rosette, ~ genotype + night temperature + experiment + plant repetition, cov.reduce = FALSE)
```

The following table exemplifies the expected output I was hoping to achieve for a subset of two genotypes:

| Genotype | night_temperature | experiment | plant_repetition | emmeans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Col-0 | 20 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| Col-0 | 20 | 1 | 2 | 15 |
| Col-0 | 20 | 2 | 1 | 17 |
| Col-0 | 20 | 3 | 1 | 13 |
| Lz-0 | 20 | 1 | 1 | 20 |
| Lz-0 | 20 | 2 | 1 | 16 |
| Lz-0 | 20 | 3 | 1 | 23 |
| Col-0 | 15 | 1 | 1 | 8 |
| Col-0 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 12 |
| Col-0 | 15 | 3 | 1 | 17 |
| Lz-0 | 15 | 1 | 1 | 13 |
| Lz-0 | 15 | 1 | 2 | 15 |
| Lz-0 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 19 |

Nevertheless, this is the actual given output:

| Genotype | night_temperature | experiment | plant_repetition | emmeans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Col-0 | 20 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| Col-0 | 20 | 1 | 2 | 15 |
| Col-0 | 20 | 2 | 1 | 17 |
| Col-0 | 20 | 3 | 1 | 13 |
| Lz-0 | 20 | 1 | 1 | 20 |
| Lz-0 | 20 | 1 | 2 | 18 |
| Lz-0 | 20 | 2 | 1 | 16 |
| Lz-0 | 20 | 3 | 1 | 23 |
| Col-0 | 15 | 1 | 1 | 8 |
| Col-0 | 15 | 1 | 2 | 9 |
| Col-0 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 12 |
| Col-0 | 15 | 3 | 1 | 17 |
| Lz-0 | 15 | 1 | 1 | 13 |
| Lz-0 | 15 | 1 | 2 | 15 |
| Lz-0 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 19 |
| Lz-0 | 15 | 3 | 1 | 22 |

In the actual output, it is considered that the two genotypes have the same number of repetitions in each experiment and night temperature, when is actually not the case.

I read about the option of setting **weights = "proportional"** in the emmeans function, but I am not yet sure if this is the better approach for this dataset.

Would you have a suggestion on how to obtain the emmeans of the trait leaf_area separately for each genotype, night temperature, experiment and repetition?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: I have mostly questions. You say it is an experiment, but then why is it so unbalanced? That is, in an experiment, we *control* the experimental conditions. So why weren't they chosen to make it balanced? Second, what's the distinction between `experiment` and `experiment_setup`? From your description, I'd have guessed that `experiment` would be a random effect. Third, I notice that you fitted an additive model (no interactions). Did you consider models with interaction effects? They seem likely to occur here.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Regarding your questions: 1) it is unbalanced because genotypes seeds did not germinate uniformly across all experiments and/or some seedlings did not survive after transplanting. This resulted in genotypes having different number of repetitions. 2) the experiment refers to the experiment number and the experiment_setup is a coordinate to describe the place within the tray where plants grew so we could account for spatial heterogeneity. 3) I have not tried interaction, but I will have a look at it, Thank you.

Comment: OK, well the starting point for `emmeasn` should be a model that fits well; otherwise, the GIGO principle applies. But usually, with experimemental data, we would *not* use proportional weights because you want to give equal weights to the test conditions. The other weighting options are most appropriate for observational data.

Comment: And you might consider another analysis where the germination rate is the response (e.g., a Poisson model), if success in germination is of interest.

Comment: I understand, the model fitted well to the data, but still I would like to get the means separately for the variables. Would you suggest that the weighting option could enable this or this is not possible in the `emmeans` package? Thank you.

Comment: It's your experiment, so it's your decision. And yes it is possible to use weighting. Look fir example at the vignette on messy data, of the help page for emmeans. But if you want statistical advice, you should ask on CfossValidated. All I'll say here is that with designed experiments, people usually opt for equal weights because they are not trying to represent the incidences of factor levels ina population.